# What's the best way to obtain cosine similarity from two vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, cosine-similarity

I'll need to repeat this process multiple times, and the number of values will vary from ~10 to ~1000. I don't have access to all the vectors at once - they'll become accessible to me two vectors at a time.

In each instance there will always be the same number of values in each of the pair of vectors. However, from instance to instance the number of values will vary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate cosine similarity between two frequency vectors in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187941/how-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-between-two-frequency-vectors-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

For column vectors **a** and **b** I might try,

a.'*b/(norm(a)*norm(b))

Ideally you would combine all or a subset of your vectors into arrays and do the operations at once, taking advantage of matlab multi threading. Different length vectors is a challenge though...

Do you have access to all the vectors at once?

Comment: Just clarified my original post to answer your question.