# How to calculate cosine similarity between two frequency vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, cosine-similarity

I need to find the cosine similarity between two frequency vectors in MATLAB.

Example vectors:

```
a = [2,3,4,4,6,1]
b = [1,3,2,4,6,3]
```

How do I measure the cosine similarity between these vectors in MATLAB?

Comment: I do not have Matlab here anymore to test for you, but I believe the function in the following link can be a quick help for what you need (see tab "Functions"): https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/62978-getcosinesimilarity-x-y

Answer (score 3):

Take a quick look at the mathematical definition of [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

From the definition, you just need the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Dot_product) of the vectors divided by the product of the [Euclidean norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) of those vectors.

```
% MATLAB 2018b
a = [2,3,4,4,6,1]; 
b = [1,3,2,4,6,3];

cosSim = sum(a.*b)/sqrt(sum(a.^2)*sum(b.^2));            % 0.9436
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
cosSim = (a(:).'*b(:))/sqrt(sum(a.^2)*sum(b.^2));        % 0.9436
```

which gives the same result.

---

After reading [this correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57188153/8239061), to avoid sending you to [another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/476162) I've added another approach using MATLAB's built-in linear algebra functions, [`dot()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) and [`norm()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html).

```
cosSim = dot(a,b)/(norm(a)*norm(b));                     % 0.9436
```

See also the [tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cosine-similarity/info) for [cosine-similarity](/questions/tagged/cosine-similarity).

---

**Performance by Approach:**

1. `sum(a.*b)/sqrt(sum(a.^2)*sum(b.^2))`
2. `(a(:).'*b(:))/sqrt(sum(a.^2)*sum(b.^2))`
3. `dot(a,b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))`

[image: Runtime performance test showing Approach 3 (dot & norm) is faster for very large vectors]

Each point represents the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) of the computation times for 10 randomly generated vectors.

Comment: @quart-ul-ainabid I'm testing to verify but I'm guessing the approach using [`dot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) & [`norm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) will be faster for large vectors (many elements) but any reasonable vector length won't show a difference in run time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Statistics toolbox, you can use the [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) function with the `'cosine'` input flag, which gives 1 minus the cosine similarity:

```
a = [2,3,4,4,6,1];
b = [1,3,2,4,6,3];
result = 1-pdist2(a, b, 'cosine');
```

Comment: Very clever - I wouldn't have thought about the `pdist2` function (+1). After reading through the documentation, it is a very versatile tool.